# Setting num_epochs on tf.train.string_input_producer produces an error

Tags: tensorflow

Setting num_epochs on tf.train.string_input_producerto anything other than None produces the error

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer/limit_epochs/epoch
```

What causes this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 9):

This error is caused by not initializing local variables. To ensure local variables are initialized you should do something like the following.

```
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)
```

Comment: Now `init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())` since the line above uses 2 deprecated functions